# Saving hebrew utf08 to mongoDB - mongoose comes Giberish

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there any way to define mongodb/nodejs/mongoosejs to be capable of reading hebrew characters? I'm saving from input and it is saved as '???\"?'

I'm not really sure where i set this to be able.

e.g

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55b51dc26eb78bd00ed79fe6"),
    "itemName" : "???\"?",
    "itemCategory" : "Food",
    "exists" : true,
    "__v" : 0
```

My HTML page has the meta

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after knowing that mongoDB automaticaly saves UTF8 it's seemed wierd to me that i see gibberish. so i did a small check

on the shell it showed gibberish but on view when called it's shows fine.

meaning only the mongo.exe (the shell) can't read the characters but they are indeed saves as hebrew.

thanks anyway.

Comment: It is probably the shell you are using. If you are using something like Putty you need to set it to show utf8

Comment: yeah , i guess it's somewhere in the settings. i'm using Webstroms terminal